# how to compare an integer with a lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

```
public static bool StudentUpdate(string studentId)
{
    using (var db = new UniversityContext())
    {
        int idtoupdate = Convert.ToInt32(studentId);
        Student temp = db.Students.Where((a => a.Id) == idtoupdate)
                                  .SingleOrDefault();
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp.FirstName = feilds[0];
            temp.LastName = feilds[1];
            temp.Average = Convert.ToSingle(feilds[2]);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I need to update some information stored on a database using entity framework but when I try this code I get the following error message:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'int'

what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: just write it as `a => a.Id == idtoupdate`

Comment: Explanation: Lambdas are kind of like 'independent operations'. It looks like you want to do a comparison, i.e. `== idtoupdate`, so you'll have to include the comparison _inside_ the lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Student temp = db.Students.Where(a => a.Id == idtoupdate).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got bracket in the wrong place it should be `Where((a) => a.Id == idtoupdate)`.

Also, as Ulugbek notes, for a single parameter the brackets aren't necessary and you could do `Where(a => a.Id == idtoupdate)`.

Comment: brackets are not required for single parameter

Comment: your example omitting the parenthesis on the single parameter doesn't actually omit them.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda

```
a => a.Id
```

is equivalent to

```
delegate(Student a) { return a.Id; }
```

i.e. it takes a `Student` and returns the `Id` of that student.  On the other hand, the lambda

```
a => a.Id == idtoupdate
```

is equivalent to

```
delegate(Student a) { return a.Id == idtoupdate; }
```

and returns a `bool` value indicating whether or not that `Student` has the `Id` you want to match.

Where you can get the hint as to which you should use is in the definition of the `Where` extension method, which is documented as taking a `Func<int, bool> predicate`, i.e. a function which takes an `int` (the Id you want to match) and returns a `bool` (i.e. whether or not each one matches the supplied Id).